# Remove a portion of XML, edit it, then add back to xml at original position

Tags: c#, xml, regex, linq-to-xml, cdata

So what I'm ultimately trying to do is parse XML and add element values to an element that is contained within a cdata section. I search for the cdata section within the xml pull it out and load it in another xdocument so as to keep the xml structure and then I add the element values but now I'm not sure how to add it back to the original xml at the original position.

Here is the original XMl:

```
  <OUTPUT version="2.0"><RESPONSE><DATA state="FL" city="Sarasota">
      <![CDATA[<LION xmlns="http://www.com" version="5.050">
      <COMMENTS>
        <PLACES>   
          Forest under a tree
         </PLACES></COMMENTS></LION>]]>
   </DATA></RESPONSE></OUTPUT>
```

I search for the cdata section and insert element values like this:

```
XDocument value = XDocument.Parse(returnValue);
RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.None;
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\<\!\[CDATA\[(?<text>[^\]]*)\]\]\>", options);

bool isMatch = regex.IsMatch(returnValue);
if(isMatch)
{
  Match match = regex.Match(returnValue);                   
  string HTMLtext = match.Groups["text"].Value;
  XDocument cdata = XDocument.Parse(HTMLtext);
  XNamespace ns = @"http://www";
  var com = cdata.Descendants(ns + "COMMENTS").First();
  var dcomm = com.Element(ns + "PLACES");
  dcomm.Value = "test"+ dcomm.Value;
```

What I have left is to append back on the cdata text because that was removed converting regex to string and then place it back at the position of the cdata in the original xml.

Comment: Parsing and constructing XML with Regular expressions and string concatenation is bad idea. If you enjoy painful problems with encoding consider doing so in private, but for public samples please try to use proper XML manipulation classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can test to see if the node is cdata without having to use regex using the NodeType property.  In example we try to cast to XCData to test.

```
 XElement root = XElement.Parse(input);
                XElement dataElement = root.Descendants("DATA").FirstOrDefault();
                XCData cdata = dataElement == null ? null : dataElement.FirstNode as XCData;
                if (cdata == null)
                {
                    return;
                }

                XElement nestedXml = XElement.Parse(cdata.Value);
                XNamespace ns = @"http://www.com";
                var com = nestedXml.Descendants(ns + "PLACES").First();

                com.Value = "Incomplete App Email sent to member." + com.Value;

                cdata.Value = nestedXml.ToString(SaveOptions.DisableFormatting);
                string updatedOutput = cdata.ToString();
```

Comment: I'm been trying to do this for a few days now and finally got it to extract the cdata out. And you come in and provide me a way easier solution to the whole problem at hand. Thanks!